# Different row border color around table

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have a simple html table on wordpress. I want a different border color for every row, or even create a little gap around every row. How can i do this?

I tried in this way:

```
<table style="border-collapse: collapse;">
 <tbody>
  <tr style="border: 1px solid black;">
   <th>Zoo (Country)</th>
   <th>Date of Birth</th>
   <th>Name</th>
   <th>Dam (number of calves)</th>
   <th>Sire</th>
  </tr>
  <tr style="color: darksalmon; border: 1px solid green;">
   <td>Knowsley (UK)</td>
   <td>2 Jan 2016</td>
   <td>Nomvula</td>
   <td>Meru (9)</td>
   <td>Sharka</td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

But I obtained this:
[image: html_error]

in which you can see green border and black border overlaps

Comment: Please post some existing code you have tried. [Read here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for more information about how to create a Minimal, Complete and Verifiable question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to change the color of every row you will need to pass a different id with every row specifying the color.

for the little gap you can give a class, or you could do some inline styling as shown with this example

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
table, th, td {
    border: 1px solid black;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table>
  <tr border-color="#FF0000">
    <th>Month</th>
    <th>Savings</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>January</td>
    <td>$100</td>
  </tr>
</table>

<p>The bgcolor attribute is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: for the gap I added empty rows in the table... but still don't know if there's a way to have different border colors.

Comment: for the gap you can also add margin-bottom: 10px, and normally adding the border-color="#colorhex" should do the trick